# Drawbacks of having pruned and collapsed packets

Tags: networking, tcp, packet-capture

I am a newbie in networking field, I come across a note that we should not have pruned packets and collapsed packets, if we have, we should have to optimize the system.

But the note (neither the internet) didn't provide much context on why we shouldn't have pruned and collapsed packets and what problems that it makes?

```
$ netstat -s | grep socket      
299 packets pruned from receive queue because of socket buffer overrun
2701 TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
5 delayed acks further delayed because of locked socket
92 packets collapsed in receive queue due to low socket buffer
```

Here, you can see I have 299 packets which were pruned and 92 packets were collapsed.

Is it bad? if yes, why? what issues I will face due to this?

Comment: This is an indication of app(s) unable to cope with the traffic, tuning buffers size could or couldn't help, it needs examination rather in whole.

Comment: But I don't see any issues as a user. Note that the above metrics are from my laptop.
I am specifically interested in what impact it will do for those apps? and the system in general?

Comment: But why are you using "But"? There's no contradiction, not all failures are always fatal. )